# Writing efficient code

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I am new to programming and trying to get better at writing efficient  code.

The obvious thing to do is practice and gain experience.

I did learn a few general pointers through exercising, but in most cases, the only option is to simply think of a better algorithm to solve a given problem.

What would be a good source (free or paid) to learn from about how to "think of that better algorithm"?

Comment: `new to programming and trying to get better at writing efficient code` Writing readable, maintainable code will go a long way in the direction of efficiency. Then, there is increase in resource usage with problem size and "asymptotically" efficient algorithms, and there is *premature optimisation*. Until successfully assessing resource usage in *Real Life™*, sacrificing *anything* (including life time) for conceived efficiency advantages *is* premature.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Bentley's [Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880). Not specifically about efficiency, but most of the advice in it does have an important bearing on it. A classic (sadly out of print) is his [Writing Efficient Programs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013970244X). Relevant is also Kernighan and Pike's [The Practice of Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161586X).

But it is critical to design and write clean, understandable programs first. Most of the time the "efficiency" is irrelevant (i.e., shaving off a half second of execution time to have the user then thinking for half a minute what to do next is a terrible use of your time). Just think what an hour of your time is worth, and how much a second of computer time is worth. You'll have to factor in not only the development time (writing an efficient, well tuned program is harder than you think, ad it is *much* harder still to fix if something changes later on). As the saying goes, debugging is twice as hard as writing the program in the first place. If you write the cleverest program you can, you have no chance of fixing it.

Programmers are *terrible* at estimating where the program spends most resources, Bentley gives some hilarious blunders (and some instructive success stories too). Program, *measure* and then consider where the effort to make more efficient is best spent (if warranted). Note that current compilers are *extremely* good ad generating code, specially at high "optimization" levels. For most micro-optimizations you'd come up with (e.g., reuse a variable, write some expression differently --add `x + x` instead of `2 * x`, shift instead of multiplying by a power of 2--, compute a common subexpression once, and so on) you'll find that your favourite compiler has them already covered, and then some. If in doubt, ask for assembly output and check.